# Python/Matplotlib/Subplots/Pandas: Not existing values at the beginning and the end of the x-axis are cut off

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I load in a dataframe with electrical load values for around 2,5 years recorded in a 15 min interval beginning at 2018-04-01 00:15 and ending at 2020-09-03 00:15. Now I want to compare the load for the different years visually.

I display the result in a subplot with the following code:

```
df_compare = ...imagine this is a large dataframe

years = ['2018', '2019', '2020']

plt.figure()
for i in range(len(years)):
    ax = plt.subplot(len(years), 1, i+1)
    year = years[i]
    result = df_compare[str(year)]
    plt.plot(result['Total_consumption'])
    plt.title(str(year), y=0, loc='left')
plt.show()
```

The result I get:
[image]
As you can see the months Jan to Mar 2018 are cut off and resized because there are no values existing. The same for Sept to Dec 2020.

The result I want to display is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the axes limits in your loop:

```
for i in range(len(years)):
    ax = plt.subplot(len(years), 1, i+1)
    year = years[i]
    result = df_compare[str(year)]
    plt.plot(result['Total_consumption'])
    plt.title(str(year), y=0, loc='left')
    plt.xlim(f'{year}-01-01',f'{year}-12-31')
```

Comment: Thank you my friend :-)